# Does alter self also change the caster's voice?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Alter Self says:

> When you cast this spell, you can assume the form of any Small or Medium creature of the humanoid type. If the form you assume has any of the following abilities, you gain the listed ability: darkvision 60 feet, low-light vision, scent, and swim 30 feet.

But then there is also a spell called Vocal Alteration:

> You alter the target’s voice to something else. For example, you could make the target’s voice high-pitched, husky, or nasal, or change its accent to an accent you are familiar with. If this spell is used as part of a disguise, the target gets a +10 bonus on the Disguise check when trying to fool a listener.
>
> The target can vary the disguised voice just as it could its normal voice. For example, a halfling female given a male dwarf noble’s voice and accent could speak in falsetto, with a rural halfling accent, and so on.

Does Alter Self also have a built-in Vocal Alteration? Or if the caster wants to sound like the humanoid they turned into, do they have to cast Vocal Alteration separately?

Alter Self is a level 2 spell while Vocal Alteration is a level 1 spell.

If it makes a difference, I am asking this question from the perspective of a Kitsune wanting to use Realistic Likeness (which "functions like Alter Self") to sound like other people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes, it does

Unlike [Illusion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Illusion) spells, that must specify what can be modified, [Transmutation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Transmutation) spells can change your body completely, like here with [Alter Self](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/alter-self). Consdering it is from the *Polymorph* subschool, it changes your shape to match the desired humanoid form and will grant you +10 on your Disguise checks (among other things), which does help to sound like someone else.

> **Polymorph**: a polymorph spell transforms your physical body to take on the shape of another creature. While these spells make you appear to be the creature, granting you a +10 bonus on Disguise skill checks, they do not grant you all of the abilities and powers of the creature.

This [other question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/95113/21153) goes through the differences between Realistic Likeness and Disguise Self.

However, to mimic a *specific* person's voice, you must either use [Vocal Alteration](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/v/vocal-alteration/), which grants another +10 on your Disguise checks, or another special ability like the [Infiltrator](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/investigator/archetypes/paizo-investigator-archetypes/infiltrator/)'s **Voice Mimicry**, which allows you to use Disguise to change your voice.